# How to fix spaCy en_training incompatible with current spaCy version

Tags: python, spacy

```
UserWarning: [W094] Model 'en_training' (0.0.0) specifies an under-constrained spaCy version requirement: >=2.1.4. 
This can lead to compatibility problems with older versions, 
or as new spaCy versions are released, because the model may say it's compatible when it's not. 
Consider changing the "spacy_version" in your meta.json to a version range,
 with a lower and upper pin. For example: >=3.2.1,<3.3.0
```

spaCy version    3.2.1
Python version   3.9.7
OS Window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For spacy v2 models, the under-constrained requirement `>=2.1.4` means `>=2.1.4,<2.2.0` in effect, and as a result this model will only work with spacy v2.1.x.

There is no way to convert a v2 model to v3. You can either use the model with v2.1.x or retrain the model from scratch with your training data.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install spacy==2.1.4
```

This can download required